Spring Boot application not working with @PreAuthoriz
I have a Spring Boot application where I want to secure an endpoint using Spring Security's @PreAuthorize annotation. However, my application isn't working as expected.
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ProaccountRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProaccountRestApplication.class, args);
    }

@GetMapping("/home")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_Admin')")
public String getHome (){
    return "Yes";
}

 
}


this is my RestController and it carries
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter:2.3.5'
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory:5.12.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:3.2.3'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'

all this dependencies
I want to use Microsoft Entra Id for to create role-based system for current services

Please add what is not working (log messages, etc) to your question. That makes it easier for people to help you in the right direction

You forgot @EnableMethodSecurity

When I use that annotation, I get a whitelabel error.

What is the console output when you get a whitelabel error?

@akashy-hole you are probably missing quite some Spring Security configuration for method security to behave the way you expect, but the reason why @PreAuthorize is ignored in the code you exposed in your question is the missing @EnableMethodSecurity. What to configure to map Entra ID roles to Spring authorities, and your app as an OAuth2 resource server (or client) are different topics.

You may start here for some minimum OAuth2 background and configuration tutorials: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials
